# backbone model.destroy not triggering a DELETE request

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

This is my model.

```
library.BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/books',
    defaults: {
        id      : null,
        imageurl: 'noimage.jpg', 
    }
});
```

I'm trying to issue a delete request by calling book.destroy. But it is not triggering the request. When the app is initialized. The model is populated with data from server. There are two IDs attributes set in the model. `id`(client side id) and `_id`(mongodb id). I initialized the client side id as book.attributes.id = book.attributes._id in model initialize function. So Everything is set. But i can't seem to initiate the delete request. please tell me where I'm going wrong. Am I missing anything here?

my backend router is defined as such to handle delete request.

`app.delete('/api/books/:id', function(req, res){...});`

Comment: try putting "idAttribute: '_id'" as mentioned in the answer by pramod.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting the id attribute using [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) which for your case (mongodb) is `_id`. This is the id set by the server.

```
library.BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: '/api/books',

    idAttribute: '_id',

    defaults: {
        imageurl: 'noimage.jpg', 
    }

});
```

The id set automatically by Backbone on the client is [cid](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) and not id. cid can be used until the model is synced on the server and gets a server id.

Comment: 'idAttribute', write full attribute name, 'idAttr' might not work.

Comment: Woot thank you! After half an hour of searching this is by far the most elegant solution.